# jQuery.ajax() to PHP always enters "request.fail" function

Tags: jquery

I'll try to be as descriptive as possible. Sorry if it's too much.

I have an HTML file, with a simple login form, linking jquery and my personal script:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

 <title>Login</title>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/50load-json.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

<h1>Login Form</h1>
 <form id="myform">
        Username<br>    <input type="text"      name="username" id="username"><p>
        <!--Password    <input type="password"  name="password"> -->
        Password<br>    <input type="text"      name="password" id="password"><p>
                        <input type= 'submit' value='Login' id="submitLogin">
 </form>    
<div id="output"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

From my script (50load-json.js) I call a PHP, which connects to my DB and does a query to match the username and password.

The code of my js file is the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#myform").submit( function () { 
    var output = $('#output');    
            var my_post_data = "username=bloc&password=party";//These Parameters should evaluate as TRUE in the PHP

      $.post("loginthisPOST.php", my_post_data)
   .done(function(data) { alert("Data Loaded: " + data);})
   .fail(function(data) { alert("error: " + data); });
       });    
       });
```

my "loginthisPOST.php" looks like this:

```
 <?php
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');

   $u = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
   $p = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

   $con = mysql_connect("database","username","password");
   if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
        mysql_select_db ("phpmy1_bumblast_com");
        $sorgu="SELECT * from users WHERE username ='$u' AND password ='$p' ";
        $ssql_select = mysql_query($sorgu)or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($ssql_select)>0)
        {
           echo 'true';
        }else{
           echo 'false'; 
        }      
        mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

My plan is to make this "dynamic", obviously (adding a `var values = $(this).serialize();` code to my "js" file and then passing those parameters as "my_post_data" ), but I can't even call the PHP successfully with static data. It always executes the "fail" function. To be more specific it gives me these message "error: [object Object]".

I uploaded my test site, just in case I can't make this kind of requests via MAMP, but it also fails.

My "test" page is published here:

http://www.capitalbecarios.org/phonegap_tests/50login.html

Additionally I also have a "loginthisGET.php" for testing purposes right here (passing the username and password which are actually correct, so evaluates as "TRUE"):

http://www.capitalbecarios.org/phonegap_tests/js/loginthisGET.php?username=bloc&password=party

The "50load-json.js" and "loginthisPOST.php" are both located in the "js" folder where "50login.html" is.

Also, why if I do `$("#output").html('there is error while submit 1');` it displays it but then removes it quite fast, because it refreshes the page?.

Can you please help this ignorant soul to achieve enlightenment?

Thank you for your attention to this note.

Comment: Updated the question following the suggestions. Problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding a `return false;` in the submit handler:

```
$("#myform").submit( function () { 
  var my_post_data = $("#myform").serialize();    
  $.post("loginthisPOST.php", my_post_data)
  .done(function(data) { alert("Data Loaded: " + data);})
  .fail(function(data) { alert("error: " + data); });
  return false;
});
```

What's happening is that two POST requests are being sent: your `$.post();` and the original form's submit. When the second request begins, it cancels all pending XMLHttpRequests generating a "cancelled" error for each one of them (thus entering the fail function). This is also why you're seeing a page refresh when you dismiss the error alert.

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated]** As you're using jQuery, consider using [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$("#myform").submit( function () {
   var my_post_data = $("#myform").serialize(); 
   // Or = "username=bloc&password=party" for testing
   $.post("loginthis.php", my_post_data, function (msg){
       //A callback function for your post
       alert(msg);
   }); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!. I corrected that, the issue persisted.

Comment: I tried with the `$.post`method, the function receives the response in the variable "msg" and I try to output the message with `alert(msg);`...Every time I click "login" the page only refreshes, it never ALERTS anything. Thank you for your patience!.

Comment: @hugojl Make sure your `action` attribute is empty on your `form` tag, and try to remove your `enctype` attribute

Comment: This time, when I hit LOGIN I get "error: [object Object]". I'm not using `var my_post_data = $("#myform").serialize(); `, but rather `var my_post_data = "username=bloc&password=party"` for testing. I really appreciate your persistence.

Comment: @hugojl Could you update your code on your question? Note : is your `loginthis.php` on the same server than your webpage? If not, use header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *') at the beginning of your webservice.

Comment: @ Bigood ...Hi!!, yes loginthis.php is on the same server where my page is. I put the "header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')" anyway, and the problem persists. Updated my question as requested, if you have a chance I published my test site so you can see it in action. Thank you